# Runtime reload of environment variables

Tags: java, environment-variables, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to listen to a change event in the environment variable from a java application? I am interested to know on how to actually identify that the underlying environment variable has changed at runtime & act on it? In the below code, I would like the application to be notified when the `env.var` changes in the environment. We are using Java 8 on PCF platform.

```
@Value("${env.var}")
private String envVar;
```

Comment: Are you changing the environment variables from the process itself?  That is the only way the process will see those changes.

Comment: As the CLI reminds you, when you change an env var, if you want that to change the running app, you need to restage (or at least restart) it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your OS platform, this is not possible; each process gets a copy of the environment variables, there isn't really such a thing as a 'global' environment table - the environment variables of a process that is in charge of launching most processes seems global-ish, perhaps, as you inherit environment variables from the process that launched your process (unless during your process being launched, modifications to the environment variables were applied), so what you're effectively asking for is 'can I observe any changes to environment variables as in the process that spawned me', which is, amongst other things, rather hairy from a security perspective, which leads to the rather obvious answer of: No, you can't do that.

Maybe take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. Maybe you want the ability to live-configure your application, and you chose 'this setting will be conveyed to the app by way of my OS's environment variable system' - which is one of many ways to accomplish the goal of having a setting system. It's a way that does not lend itself to live updates very well.

If you instead convey settings via a file, well, it is much simpler to keep a 'watch' on  a file and trigger a re-read of it when it changes, for example.

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot. You described my problem accurately, i am essentially trying to live configure (or re-configure) my application using environment variables. A file based configuration would be straightforward, but unfortunately our app runs on PCF, which limits file manipulations on a running container.

Comment: It runs on the french communist party? That's.. quite a feat! Check whatever PCF might be for documentation on how to make things happen. Worst case scenario, set up a TCP port and use that, but that starts being ... a bit of an overengineered solution at some point.